# Как создать range(start,end,step) с float параметрами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Функция `range(stop) | range(start, stop[, step])` возвращает последовательность чисел, начиная от нижней границы до верхней границы с указанным шагом. И параметры должны быть целыми числами.

Как создать диапазон float значений? что-то подобное `frange(0, 1.5, 0.1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [40]: import numpy as np

In [41]: np.arange(0, 1.5, 0.1)
Out[41]: array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. , 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4])
```

если есть границы диапазона (оба конца должны принадлежать диапазону) и число необходимых точек:

```
In [46]: np.linspace(0, 1.4, 15)
Out[46]: array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. , 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4])
```

без Numpy:

```
In [42]: [x/10 for x in range(15)]
Out[42]: [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]
```