# Python for i in range float

Tags: python

Как на питоне с помощью `for i in range` (с range от 0 до 10) вывести 40 чисел?
Если `float` нельзя в `range` засунуть.

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Как создать range(start,end,step) с float параметрами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/869824), [Ошибка TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer в range](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1132284)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот вариант на чистом Python:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    for j in range(0, 4):
        x = (i * 4 + j) / 3.9 # или / 4, если число 10 не должно выводиться
        print(x)
```

Вывод:

```
0.0
0.25641025641025644
0.5128205128205129
0.7692307692307693
1.0256410256410258
1.2820512820512822
1.5384615384615385
1.794871794871795
2.0512820512820515
2.307692307692308
2.5641025641025643
2.8205128205128207
3.076923076923077
3.3333333333333335
3.58974358974359
3.8461538461538463
4.102564102564103
4.3589743589743595
4.615384615384616
4.871794871794872
5.128205128205129
5.384615384615385
5.641025641025641
5.897435897435898
6.153846153846154
6.410256410256411
6.666666666666667
6.923076923076923
7.17948717948718
7.435897435897436
7.6923076923076925
7.948717948717949
8.205128205128206
8.461538461538462
8.717948717948719
8.974358974358974
9.230769230769232
9.487179487179487
9.743589743589745
10.0
```

Answer (score 5):

для 40 чисел и цикл нужен с 40 шагами

другое дело, что 40 чисел легко уместить в заданный диапазон значений

```
for i in range(0, 40):
    print(10 * i / 40)
```

более универсально:

```
l = -10
r = 30
steps = 40

for i in range(steps):
    print(l + i * (r - l) / (steps - 1))
```

P.S.

ну если нужно конкретно `range(10)`, то тогда например так:

```
for i in range(10):
    print((i * 4 + 0) / 4)
    print((i * 4 + 1) / 4)
    print((i * 4 + 2) / 4)
    print((i * 4 + 3) / 4)
```

или так:

```
value = 0

while value < 10:
    print(value)
    value += 10 / 40
```

Comment: Но мне нужно как-то с рейнджом (0,10)

Comment: @Bender, а что вы на выходе хотите получить тогда?

Comment: for i in range(0,10) и на выходе нужно получить 40 чисел. Нужно что-то ещё дописать, но что?

Comment: @Bender ну можно внутри `i in range(10)` запустить еще один `j in range(4)` и выводить `i + 0.25 * j` но это какое-то искусственное огранчиение)

Comment: @Bender, `for` в питоне так не работает, тогда вам нужен `while` (добавил в свой ответ пример) - range создает лишь список целых чисел

Answer (score 4):

Не очень понял, что вы хотите, но может быть так.
Библиотека `Numpy` вообще содержит много полезных готовых функций для таких вещей.

```
import numpy as np

for x in np.linspace(0, 10, 40):
    print(x)
```

Вывод:

```
0.0
0.2564102564102564
0.5128205128205128
0.7692307692307692
1.0256410256410255
1.282051282051282
1.5384615384615383
1.7948717948717947
2.051282051282051
2.3076923076923075
2.564102564102564
2.8205128205128203
3.0769230769230766
3.333333333333333
3.5897435897435894
3.846153846153846
4.102564102564102
4.358974358974359
4.615384615384615
4.871794871794871
5.128205128205128
5.384615384615384
5.6410256410256405
5.897435897435897
6.153846153846153
6.41025641025641
6.666666666666666
6.9230769230769225
7.179487179487179
7.435897435897435
7.692307692307692
7.948717948717948
8.205128205128204
8.46153846153846
8.717948717948717
8.974358974358974
9.23076923076923
9.487179487179485
9.743589743589743
10.0
```

Comment: Нужно сделать без нумпая

Answer (score 4):

```
def frange(start, stop, count):
    i = start
    step = (stop - start) / count
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i += step

for i in frange(0, 10, 40):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
start = 0
stop  = 10
num   = 40

[start + i * (stop-start) / num for i in range(num)]
```

Результат:

> ```
> [0.0,
>  0.25,
>  0.5,
>  0.75,
>  1.0,
>  1.25,
>  1.5,
>  1.75,
>  2.0,
>  2.25,
>  2.5,
>  2.75,
>  3.0,
>  3.25,
>  3.5,
>  3.75,
>  4.0,
>  4.25,
>  4.5,
>  4.75,
>  5.0,
>  5.25,
>  5.5,
>  5.75,
>  6.0,
>  6.25,
>  6.5,
>  6.75,
>  7.0,
>  7.25,
>  7.5,
>  7.75,
>  8.0,
>  8.25,
>  8.5,
>  8.75,
>  9.0,
>  9.25,
>  9.5,
>  9.75]
> ```